# Ordering methods in java

Tags: java

So this is the case: I want my java output to show me the the reverse order in a certain array, the sum of the numbers in that same array, and the largest number. However when I first tried out my code, in which I inserted the values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10:

```
import java.util.*;
public class AssignSeven {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] array1=new int[10];
    System.out.println("Enter 10 numbers");
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i=0;
         i < 10;
         i++) {
      int a=sc.nextInt();
      array1[i]=a;
    }
    sc.close();
    printReverse(array1);
    computeTotal(array1);
    getLargest(array1);
  }
  static void printReverse(int[] array1) {
    for (int i=0;
         i < array1.length / 2;
         i++) {
      int temp=array1[i];
      array1[i]=array1[array1.length - 1 - i];
      array1[array1.length - 1 - i]=temp;
    }
    System.out.println("The numbers in reverse order is: " + Arrays.toString(array1));
  }
  static void computeTotal(int[] array1) {
    int total=0;
    for (int j=0;
         j < array1.length;
         j++) {
      total=total + array1[j];
    }
    System.out.println("The sum of these numbers is: " + total);
  }
  static void getLargest(int[] array1) {
    int c;
    int d=0;
    for (c=0;
         c < 9;
         c++) {
      if (array1[c] < array1[c+1]) {
        d=array1[c+1];
      }
      else {
        d=array1[c];
      }
    }
    System.out.println("The highest value is: " + d);
  }
}
```

The results show as:

```
The numbers in reverse order is: [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

The sum of these numbers is: 55

The highest value is: 2
```

Of course, the last portion is wrong, whereas it should be 10 instead of 2. However, when I set the method call in this order

```
computeTotal(array1);
getLargest(array1);
printReverse(array1);
```

The results show the right answer. However, I want the `printReverse` method to come first. Is there any way to handle this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your get largest computation is incorrect. You need to iterate over array and check if a value at a particular index in array is greater than maximum value found so far.

```
static void getLargest(int[] array1) {
        int c;
        int d = array1[0];
        for (c = 0; c <= 9; c++) {
            if (d < array1[c]) {
                d = array1[c];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The highest value is: " + d);
    }
```

The reason why I choose d to be first value instead of zero is if all values in array are negative keeping initial value of d equal to zero will compute maximum value as 0.

Comment: Why don't you just pick the first element of the array to set as `highest value`?

Comment: @Thrasher There is no guarantee that first element is highest.

Comment: Of course **not**, but when you pick the first element it would be the **actual** current highest. Indeed, you have no guarantee that 0 would be part of the array.

Comment: Yes that is what I said.

Comment: I'm sorry. I misread your last paragraph. Your code is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This `else` statement in the `for` loop of `getLargest()` is causing the problem:

```
else {
     d = array1[c];
}
```

`d` should preserve the largest value in the array. The correct code without the `else` statement is:

```
static void getLargest ( int[] array1){
    int c;
    int d = 0;
    for (c = 0;
         c < 9;
         c++) {
        if (array1[c] < array1[c + 1]) {
            d = array1[c + 1];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The highest value is: " + d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is already answered but I want to provide an alternative solution. First, I strongly suggest the use of [naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

> Variable names should be short yet meaningful. The choice of a
> variable name should be mnemonic- that is, designed to indicate to the
> casual observer the intent of its use.

Also, there is [ternary conditional operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html), which is basically a shortcut to  `if-then-else`, and it's perfect for this situation:

```
    result = someCondition ? value1 : value2;
```

It will set `value1` when it's **true**, otherwise it will set `value2` to `result` variable.

### getLargest:

```
static void getLargest ( int [ ] array1 )
    {
        int high = array1[0];
        for ( int current : array1 )
        {
            high = current > high ? current : high; 
        }
        System.out.println ( "The highest value is: " + high );
    }
```

As you can see there is pretty much clear what is your method and body purpose.

### Output:

Finally a test.

```
Enter 10 numbers
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
The numbers in reverse order is: [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
The sum of these numbers is: 55
The highest value is: 10
```

Comment: `Math.max` would be even better than that ternary

Comment: Of course my friend, but I think he is trying to implement it by himself. We all did with learning purposes, didn't we?

Comment: True, but I don't think this one takes too much from what he's trying to learn. I mean, if we wanted to do that we could just tell him to use `Collections.reverse`. ;-P